# Why negative look behind failing

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is my search text:

```
#<localhost>
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1  localhost
127.0.0.1 local
#</localhost>
```

My Regex expression of

```
(?<=^#)(?<stuff>.+)
```

works properly, only selecting the # lines.

When I change it to `(?<!^#)(?<stuff>.+)`

to try to only get non-comment lines, it returns all lines.

I feel I am missing some obvious, any suggestions?

**Using multiline and global options**

Answer (score 0):

You need lookahead, not look behind. So try:

```
^(?!#)(?<stuff>.+)$
```

Simpler:

```
^([^#].*)$
```

This will skip both comments and empty lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely helped, thanks.   I am more curious why my look behind is failing.

Comment: Because you are not looking back (behind). Negative lookbehind would be: "all lines that are not after a #". Well, all lines are after a newline, or after the beginning of the file, so you match everything. The # is after a not-#, so it will match!

You want all lines that do not begin with #' That is plain and simple negative lookahead.

BTW I LOVE lookahead and lookbehind. ;)

Comment: The positive lookbehind works but you only get everything after the #. If you want the # as well, you need a lookahead also.  BTW I edited the 2nd regex, it skipped the first character of each line ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is probably not limiting itself after finding a character that is not a #.

Try the following to find the format you are looking for in between the lines

```
[0-9\.:]+[A-Z\.a-z\s]+
```